# How do I backup all registers in arm64?

Tags: push, arm64

The x86-64 has a pushad, but I don't know what to do with arm64.

I want to implement it with gcc inline assembly.

Comment: Why inline assembly? That will make it impossible to push to the stack in a sane way, and it will make it very hard to pass a pointer to the inline assembly without contaminating registers.

Answer (score 1):

There's no special instruction for this; you just use sixteen `stp` instructions to push all of `x0` through `x30`, two by two. If you want to save the NZCV flags also, you can `mrs Xn, NZCV` after having saved the previous value of Xn, and then push it too.

As Siguza says in comments, the idea of doing this in *inline* assembly sounds dubious.  I suspect that you may have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.